# Android Tour Screen

Tags: android

Alguém conhece alguma biblioteca que o usuário entre pela primeira vez no APP e o próprio APP mostre como usá-lo?

Comment: Acho que o que você quer é `onboarding`

Comment: https://github.com/Ramotion/paper-onboarding-android

Comment: Isso mesmo que eu procurava